# java android SlidingUp library - WebView doesn't scroll

Tags: java, android, webview, scroll

well, I think it may be not solveable, I use

https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/

library and when I set WebView on the bottom (slideable) part - it  doesn't scroll. at all.
As I suppose - it is same as setting ListView on a ScrollView.
Is there anything possible to do or at least to try??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, As far as it's not an everyday issue, but still important for those who use this wonderful Library, here's the answer to use ListViews,GridViews, WebViews and everything that may scroll on the second, hidden child.

First - you need to use method `setDragView(view)` to define which view will be used for dragging
Second - second child if it's Layout (which is most likely" should be set as `android:clickable="true"` in layout.xml

And here you are - you can scroll second child's Views too.

It's not an often issue but it was really hard to find some info in the internet

Comment: I didn't need to set android:clickable="true", but it was crucial that I setDragView(view) .... Thank you, you are a life saver!